# How to get the name of a specific icon from the Ion-icon set of react native?

Tags: android, react-native

The documentation of `react-native-vector-icon` given [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) specifies how to use these icons in the application. However each icon requires a name when you want to render it. For ex:

```
<Icon name="rocket" size={30}/>
```

I have the list of all `Ionicons` [here](http://ionicons.com/) but the names specified are not those which are used for rendering that particular icon. Where can find all such rendering names?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the available icon (syntaxe) here in your project repositories : `./nodes_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons.js` 
 It's the same path for Octicons.js / FontAwesome.js....

Comment: Yes, I found all the icon names. Is there a way to see exactly which icon corresponds to every name?

Comment: unfortunately I don't think so... You have to test them, even if the name of the icon let suppose you what is the icon... generally. Hope I help you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In Css file you may see Unicode so you can generate your own Unicode & name your icon..

Refer this link..
[Android SVG for multiple sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786989/android-svg-for-multiple-sizes/36787588#36787588)

i already answered for this Question.

Hope this may helps.